# Class not found in usual file but it's aliased

Tags: php, class, include, alias

I do this:

```
$model = new Model();
```

in `functions.php` file and php says that this class not found, but I have typed this:

```
class_alias("core\Model", "Model"),
```

and it works in `view` files and `index.php`, but what's wrong with this file? 
Includes and uses don't help me too.

Comment: Did you include functions and create the alias before trying to load model?

Comment: Ajax executes this file. I tried to include this file in `index.php`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, `class_alias` returns a boolean. If `false`, the alias failed.
You should probably assert that, or similar. `assert(class_alias("core\Model", "Model"))`.

But I believe your problem is character escaping. `\`, like `class_alias("core\\Model", "Model")`.

I'm not very familiar with PHP, just reading the docs, [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php). But the unescaped character did come very noticeably.

Comment: `class_alias` works fine, I tried to run this function in one of the `view` files and it worked there